# Javascript Can't Call Push On Array Inside Another Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, push, undefined-behavior

I have a really simple JavaScript question...

I have a function, *Pets*, that contains three variables: an integer, a string, and an array defined as follows:

```
function Pets() {
    var index;
    var name;
    var animals = ["cat", "dog"];
}
```

In another function just below this one I declare a variable of type *Pets* and push "mouse" onto the *animals* array. I then do a console log to see the values.

```
function Test() {
    ...
    var pets = new Pets();
    pets.index = 1;
    pets.name = "My Pets";
    pets.animals.push("mouse");
    console.log(pets);
}
```

For whatever reason I didn't see any output from the console.

I then added some more console logging before and after calling animals.push:

```
    var pets = new Pets();
    pets.index = 1;
    pets.name = "My Pets";
    console.log("BEFORE PUSH");
    console.log(pets);
    pets.animals.push("mouse");
    console.log("AFTER PUSH");
```

And here is my output:

```
BEFORE PUSH
Pets {index: 1, name: "My Pets"}
```

Note that I only see the first console log and not the second (after the push) which I presume indicates a problem with calling push on *animals*.

Also note that the console output shows that Pets has a property called *index* and a property called *name* but nowhere does it indicate that there is also a property called *animals* which is my array.

I tried changing the array declaration to:

```
var animals = new Array();
```

but that didn't seem to help either.

Is there something special that I have to do to initialize the animals array before I can push elements on to it? More generally, why doesn't the property animals even show up as part of the Pets class?

Thank you,

Jan

Comment: I figured it was asked somewhere else. A quick search did not yield an answer, however. I suppose my search terms were not correct. Delete away!

Comment: Does duplicating a question on Stack Overflow lower my reputation? :O

Comment: No, it just marks your question as duplicate and a banner appears above the question redirecting users to the original question. Nothing changes with your [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1586383/jan-tacci?tab=reputation)

Comment: Okay... well I accepted your answer so let's hope it sticks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your variables in a way that will not make them visible outside the the `Pets` constructor function

This is why you do not see the second console because the line

```
pets.animals.push("mouse");
```

will throw the error *TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined* (or similar depending on browser). This will cause the rest of the script to stop executing.

The only reason you see `index` and `name` in the first console log is because you are creating them on the object after creating your Pets object. You need declare them using `this` operator or by setting them up on the prototype

```
function Pets() {
    this.index = null;
    this.name = null;
    this.animals = ["cat", "dog"];
}
```

Comment: So I need to declare them first then initialize them? As follows: var this.index = null?

Comment: you do not use `var` when declaring object properties, but otherwise yes

Comment: Oh okay. So just putting this.index = null implies both initializing and "declaring" the object property?

Comment: `pets` also does not have the property `push` so you may need `Array.prototype.push.apply(pets,["mouse"]);` to do it

Comment: @13ruce1337, no OP is calling the push method on the animals array object not on the pets object

Comment: ahh I c don't mind me :D, sad part it i wrote `animals` initially and didn't think

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning the variable to the window during declaration instead of using var? Set it like window.myVar = ["var1", "var2"]

Comment: Putting variables on the global object is a bad practice, as you could accidentally overwrite an already existing property.

Comment: Okay. I will go with your suggestion then thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any of the properties of Pets this way, because they are not exposed to outer functions. You are creating the properties index and name by saying

```
pets.index = ...
```

You have to change your code like so:

```
function Pets() {
    this.index;
    this.name;
    this.animals = ["cat", "dog"];
}
function Test() {
    var pets = new Pets();
    pets.index = 1;
    pets.name = "My Pets";
    pets.animals.push("mouse");
    console.log(pets);
}
Test();
```

Comment: Yup... got it now thanks!